# How can I find out what library is dependent on junit vintage?

Tags: gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit5

I am working on a gradle project, we are switching to Junit 5 and trying to avoid having Junit 4 in our codebase.

We been noticing the error "Failed to resolve org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.2" when attempting to run, obvious we do not wish to include junit vintage in our code, because we are using Junit 5.

Is there anyway to determine what dependency is requiring that? Otherwise the code works when not running tests.

Comment: Use the dependencies task, or create a build scan with the --scan option.

Comment: I do not see any library listed in the dependency charge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which dependencies do reference a given dependency, you should use the `dependencyInsight` task with something like: `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency junit-vintage-engine` and it will tell you for the different resolvable configurations why this dependency is included.

However, given the error message, it looks more like Gradle attempts to resolve that dependency at some point and fails to do so. If that's the case, you will need to provide the more complete error message that Gradle prints before meaningful advice can be provided.